# Where llc -march=cpp option is available or not

Tags: clang, llvm-ir, llc

I would like to learn how to use properly use IRBuilder methods to generate a given bitcode using similar steps described below.

```
clang -emit-llvm test1.c -o test1.bc
llc -march=cpp test1.bc -o howto.cpp
```

Comment: Are you looking to generate c++ from LLVM IR? If so, (a) IRBuilder won't help you; as the name suggests it builds IR not c++, (b) it may not be possible. There used to be a C backend which is somewhat still maintained by the Julia people [here](https://github.com/JuliaComputing/llvm-cbe), AFAIK this is as good as it gets. If that's not what you are asking then please clarify.

Comment: The C++ backend (which is enabled by `-march=cpp`) was deprecated a long ago, so you're left with documentation only. Luckily, most LLVM classes are pretty easy to grasp, and `IRBuilder` makes the code generation even easier.